# Scaffold-DbContext ignores build errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, ef-database-first

How can I run Scaffold-DbContext while ignoring build errors ?

I removed all the modules and need to create it again. When I run the Scaffold-DbContext command it gives a lot of builds errors:

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=CONNICTION_STRING" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f

I have tried the -no-build parameter but it's not working  (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9484)

> Scaffold-DbContext : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'no-build'.
> At line:1 char:193
> + ... ntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -no-build -f
> +                                                              ~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Scaffold-DbContext], ParameterBindingException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Scaffold-DbContext

Comment: It's called `--no-build`, not `-no-build`.

Comment: I have tried `--no-build` also  and got me same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I run Scaffold-DbContext while ignoring build errors ?

You cannot run the Scaffold-DbContext command when there is a project build error. This is by design. You can submit feedback about this feature on the [EF Core forum](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose).

And from the [Scaffold-DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext), we can see there doesn't have the `-no-build` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the entities are generated in their own project and add it as a project reference.
2. Add a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Design` in this project.
3. If you have build errors in other projects in your solution, you can still regenerate by temporarily unloading those projects. (right-click on the project with errors and click "Unload project"
4. After regenerating, reload your projects. (right click on the unloaded project and click "Reload project"